# Converting SAS datetime to SQL format

Tags: sql-server, sas

I got a SAS output with datetime like this in an excel file:

25MAR2019:00:00:00.000

Any idea how I can convert thisto MM-DD-YYYY format?

if this was in epoch datetime format, I know how to convert. I tried parsing this as strings and doing it, but this is not a true string.

Comment: Are you working in SQL Server or SAS right now? What's the type of the column in either system?

Comment: "Note a true string"?  Do you mean that it is just a DATETIME value (number of seconds since 1960) that is being displayed using the DATETIME. format?

Answer (score 0):

**In SQL Server**

```
Declare @S varchar(50) = '25MAR2019:00:00:00.000'

Select AsString = convert(varchar(10),try_convert(date,stuff(stuff(left(@S,9),6,0,' '),3,0,' ')),110)
      ,AsDate   = try_convert(date,stuff(stuff(left(@S,9),6,0,' '),3,0,' '))
```

**Returns**

```
AsString    AsDate
03-25-2019  2019-03-25
```

Answer (score 0):

Format your date time variables with the SAS format [`E8601DN.`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0c419d4254oddn19koluiafrsel.htm)

> **E8601DNw. Format**
>
> Writes dates from SAS datetime values by using the ISO 8601 extended notation yyyy-mm-dd.

The ODS Excel destination will render the SAS datetime value as an Excel *date serial number* in a cell with Excel format `Number/Custom/yyyy-mm-dd`

**Example**

The datetime values in the second `PROC PRINT` use the `E8601DN.` format.

```
data have;
  my_datetime = dhms('15MAR2020'D, 0,0,0);
  format my_datetime datetime22.;              * renders as ddmonyyyy:hh:mm:ss;
run;

ods excel file='my_output.xlsx' options(sheet_interval="none");

proc print noobs data=have;
run;

proc print noobs data=have;
  format my_datetime E8601DN.;
run;

ods excel close;
```

Snip of Excel
[image]

Snip of Excel "Format Cells" dialog
[image]